# Magento 2 Admin Ui Component Edit Form Validation based on Dropdown selection

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent, ui-form

I am trying to give required field validation on textbox which is depend on dropdown selected value.

Dropdown have 2 values 1. Yes 2.No.

If dropdown selected value is Yes than textbox is mandatory else not.

This thing i want in Admin grid edit form in magento 2.

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

Add JS component to your text field.

> ui_component/UiForm.xml

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/js/form/element/text</item>
```

Write logic in your JS

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/text.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/text',      
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($,_, uiRegistry, text, modal) {
    'use strict';
    return select.extend({      

        initialize: function (){
            this.addValidation();
        },
        addValidation: function(){
            selectValue = $('input[name="labelconfig[select_field]"]').val();
            if(selectValue == 'yes') {
                $('input[name="labelconfig[text_field]"]').addClass("add magento validation class name");
            }
        }, 
    });
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: i know this will work but i don't know what logic i have to apply in js function. can you please tell me?

Comment: I have updated answer using `$('input[name="labelconfig[select_field]"]').val();` i will get value of select field and based on value you can add magento validation class using jquery.

Comment: Above code is not tested you have to check and update code.

Comment: If you can't get input field value then include JS using require config

Comment: Thanks for giving me your valuable time, i will test it and let you know does it work or not.

Comment: i am using <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</rule>
                </validation> to give validation to field than how this code work